# merging custom ribbon controls using custom ui editor

Tags: excel, ms-word, ribbon, powerpoint, vba

I have created custom ribbon control in both the 2007 and 2010. i have added few features in 2010. i wanna use these new features in 2007 also. so for merging these i have used custom ui editor tool. and i have saved this as well. when i opened up this new to the 2007 all my new controls showed up correctly. but when i open it in the 2010, the controls showed correctly without the icon images. for example, control is "Picture" then nearby this control one small image will be there. this small icon images not showing up in the 2010 version. did i do anything wrong ? please anyone help me for showing it correctly !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the icons as well to that version's xml. The pictures name must match the xml.

Click **Insert** and then **Icons...**, browse and select the pictures you want to use as button images.

You can have different sets of pictures for 2007/2010, but better to only use 2007 UI part if both versions are to be the same.

[image: InsertIcons]